# How do I filter in URL a serializer when it's nested in another serializer In Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm creating an API which has nested data like in the picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAKlt.png)

Now how to search nested data in URL
here's my model

```
class Robot(models.Model):
    robot = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    short_Description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    parameter = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    jenkins_job = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='JenkinsJobName')
    jenkins_token = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='JenkinsToken')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.robot

class assignParameter(models.Model): 
    parameterName = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    assignRobot= models.ForeignKey(Robot, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='param', blank=True, null=True)
```

Here's my serializer.py

```
from .models import Robot,assignParameter
from rest_framework import serializers

class assignParameterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = assignParameter
        fields = ['id', 'parameterName', 'assignRobot']


class RobotSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    param = assignParameterSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    JenkinJobName = jenkinsHistorySerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta: 
        model = Robot
        fields = ['id', 'robot', 'short_Description', 'status', 'parameter', 'jenkins_job', 'jenkins_token', 'param']
```

and here's my view for the api

```
class RobotViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Robot.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RobotSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['robot']
    authentication_classes = [BasicAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

in the api url if i want to search particular robot then using this url  **url/?robot=robotname** i'm able to search that particular robot . But how can i search particular nested data using URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `django-filter`:

**views.py**

```py
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

...
filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
filterset_fields = ['param__parameterName']
```

You can use `filterset_fields = ['param__parameterName']` for filtering over params name of robot

E.g url/?param__parameterName='sth' would filter robots that has param with name 'sth'

Comment: what if I want to search with parameter name instead of id ?

Comment: And also your suggestion gives this error **Unsupported lookup 'param' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.**

Comment: still not able to search the nested serializers
Now not getting any error but search is not happening